# Cycling through URLs to download csv files

Tags: web-services, csv

I have a list of URLs which will access a webservice.  The webservice downloads .csv files.  I want to be able to cycle through them using a date field which is in a specific format in the url itself, thereby downloading the data day-by-day.  The access seems fairly slow as even a manual url entry can take a couple of minutes to complete, and I suspect the issue is at the webservice' end.

The URL is in the format:
http://web.service.com/ws/XYZ/data/?key=mysecretkeyf&field1=X&start=YYYY-MM-DD 00:00&end= YYYY-MM-DD 00:00&field=Y&format=csv

So the way I envision it (and I am keen to take advice) is using a variable for the start year, month and day fields cycling onto the next URL as the previous .csv is downloaded, with the code ending when the current date is accessed.

Any ideas most welcome.

Comment: Please provide your issue or error or problem. You can use Python programming to quickly iterate through the URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coding is really straightforward which makes me wonder if you are looking to code this yourself or asking if there is a service out there that would help do this. If you are coding, I'd choose a language that works well for you. @Vivek mentioned Python which is what I would choose as well.

If you do not want to go the coding approach, you could check out DownThemAll. I have used this utility for batch downloading where you have to increment numbers in parts of the URL. Check it out, it may be a good non-programming solution: [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/howto/help/english-menu/batch-downloadsbatch-descriptors/)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I am looking to code it and will learn some Python.  Thanks for the pointer for DownThemAll, though.